# How did these characters know Officer K was a Blade Runner?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

In the movie, *Blade Runner 2049*, when Officer K goes to his apartment, ...

> somebody spray painted an insult reference to him being a Blade Runner. I don't remember the exact words, but I am pretty sure one of the words was "SKINNER", which is a reference to "skinjob", which is insult for replicants.

Later when he goes ...

> to get some dinner at an outdoor cafe, three women from a local brothel visit his table. One of the women says to the other two in a foreign (or coded?) language that he is a Blade Runner. She doesn't want to be around him. Two of the women leave, but Mariette stays with him.

**How did they know he was a Blade Runner?**

Blade Runners are undercover cops. They don't advertise their duties. Nobody is supposed to recognize them on the streets.

Comment: I'm not clear how you deduce from calling them "skinner" or "skinjob" in the first spoiler block that they knew he was a Blade Runner. Weren't they just referring to him being a replicant? As to the second incident, you ever seen a criminal "smell a cop from a mile distance" in about every crime movie ever? ;-)

Comment: Ahh but one of the replicant hookers go "I know him, he's a blade runner" so it goes a bit further than just criminal intuition

Comment: @TARS The whole thing about criminals "smelling a cop from a mile away" is just movie plot-bogus. I doubt that many criminals are so gifted in real life. If you want to use a trope to explain this, that's fine as an out-of-universe explanation, but it smells of bad scriptwriting to depend on tropes.

Comment: @TARS Your answer doesn't make sense. There's no indication the hookers were criminals.

Comment: @LincolnMan Um, you *might* be taking that a little *too* literal maybe. ;-)

Comment: @TARS What? You meant to imply the hookers are not criminals but can still smell a cop? Then why would they need a criminal's magical sense of smell that allows them to sniff out cops? Either way, whether the hookers were criminals or not, the question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Oh, I'd agree with that. ;-)

Comment: Just as background, the language was foreign (Finnish) and was spoken by an actress who is herself a Finn.   I imagine the director allowing the line to be delivered in Finnish to further enhance the feeling of a cosmopolitan melting pot that LA has become in the BR universe.

Comment: ai, yo, you gon' accept my answer or nah? ;-)

Comment: @LincolnMan The actual trope is that low-lives, marginals and people "on the street" can often spot cops, whether they are criminals or not, because they are often harassed by them and/or are informants and/or simply "know their ilk". So a thief, a drug dealer, a hooker, a neighborhood tough boy, and a homeless guy can all spot undercover cops.

Answer (score 7):

## One of the Doxies recognises him

[As pointed out by Thunderforge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/173624/21267), In the market square when K is having his noodles, one of the three Doxies recognises K and warns the others:

> The THREE DOXIES cross the market to approach K. Flank him
> at his table, studying the PHOTOS: The FARM. The BONES.
> Dead SAPPER MORTON.
> DOXIE #2
> Hello hello A-Boy... You alone ?
> DOXIE #3 recognizes him. TELLS THE OTHERS, DISGUSTED.
> DOXIE #3
> (in FINNISH, UNTRANSLATED)
> *Leave him, **he is a fucking Blade
>
> Runner... I’ve seen him.** This guy is
>
> dangerous. You coming?*
> MARIETTE
> It’s ok... I’m good.  
> <sub>-Final Shooting Script (undated), *Blade Runner 2049* (2017), Fancher, H. and Green, M.</sub>

## As for how he was recognised as a Replicant: they are now easier to tell apart

Luv tells K that in the past, Replicants were not so easy to spot as they are now. Speaking of Rachael and the Voight-Kampf test in the 'memory vault':

> The IMAGE BREAKS OFF. REPEATS again in a LOOP. The eye
> BLINKS, the voices come. A ghost fragment of an indelible
> moment. Too brief. IT PLAYS OVER AND OVER AGAIN as --
> LUV (cont’d)
> It was unclear what she was, at least to
> someone. This was a test. **We were
>
> difficult to spot then**.  
> <sub>*-Ibid.*</sub>

Now have a look at the way that Luv is described:

> LUV. Polite, efficient. Perfect. Moral as a tornado and
> about as safe. Beautiful, yes. The way a sword can be if
> it’s safely behind glass.
> ...
> Luv comes toward K. Hands tucked. Suit sensible. Every
> aspect immaculate. The flawless representative.
> LUV (cont’d)
> Another prodigal serial number returns.
> A 30 year old open case finally closed is
> a curiosity and relief. Thank you,
> Officer. I’m here for Mr. Wallace.
> (hand out)
> I’m Luv.
> K
> **He named you. You must be special.**
> He steals a once over, understanding. She gives an
> unembarrassed nod of confession.  
> <sub>*-Ibid.*</sub>

Luv is 'perfect' in every sense of the word and K pegs her immediately.

Now note how a 'normal' human is described:

> A pug COP, NANDEZ, enjoys the show. A bigot with a mouth
> certain whatever comes out of it is funny. **Recognizable as
>
> human as all humans stuck on Earth seem to be.**  
> <sub>*-Ibid.*</sub>

[all emphases mine]

Comment: It should be noted that Luv is a major character, while Nandez is not. This might be the reason for the differences in the lengths of their descriptions.

Comment: @RogueJedi It's not the _length_ of the description, it's that Nandez is _specifically_ noted as 'easy to spot for a human' whereas Luv is described as 'noticeably perfect'...

Answer (score 3):

One of the pleasure model replicants in the scene says

> "I know him, he's a Blade Runner"

I interpret "I know him" to mean that she has prior knowledge of who K is. Most likely, she knows him by reputation, or perhaps has even seen him apprehending a rogue replicant. This is just like how if someone asked me about Thomas Edison, I might say "I know him, he's an inventor."

There is no novelization for *Blade Runner 2049* and the script is not currently available, so I don't think we'll get any better information.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this in a video showing several *[Blade Runner 2049](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner_2049)* scenes.

> Officer K buys a noodle lunch at a cafe near a brothel.
>
> Brothel Manager with large sunglasses and wearing a full length body coat with hood to hide her identity (who might also be Freysa Sadeghpour, the leader of the Replicant Freedom Movement) points to Officer K: * **The one who killed Sapper.** Find out what he knows.*
>
> DOXIE #3 (in FINNISH, UNTRANSLATED) Leave him, he is a fucking Blade
> Runner... I’ve seen him. This guy is dangerous. You coming?

If that indeed was Freysa Sadeghpour, she knew K was a Blade Runner because she must have seen images of who killed Sapper Morton. We know Sapper was in contact with the Replicant Freedom Movement because of comments made by Freysa to Officer K later in the movie. Sapper probably had hidden cameras at his farm so that if he was caught, the Replicant Freedom Movement would know who found him.

Comment: The handler indeed _was_ Freysa, but she never mentions that K is a Blade Runner to the Doxies, it is inferred. The part about the Finnish one **recognising** K is the most pertinent.

Comment: @Möoz I bet Freya guessed K was a Blade Runner because few others would go after Sapper and steal his eyeball. That and the fact that a police investigation unit came to the place later that same day just to dig up the bone box. When she sees all that, she probably thinks that Sapper's killer is most likely a Blade Runner. Odd for the same Blade Runner to show up at a cafe just outside her brothel later that same night.

Comment: The fact that she was Freysa was also mentioned in an answer here. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173087/is-joi-an-unwilling-accomplice-of-either-wallace-or-the-rebellion

Comment: @Möoz Maybe the Doxie said "Blade Runner" as a code word to the other two.

Comment: All three of the spy prostitutes must have known the one in green was a Blade Runner beforehand. Notice how the prostitute with the afro initially, cautiously backed off before approaching Agent K. Then the blonde-haired prostitute identified K, but the purpose for that may have become the excuse for the blonde and the afro to leave, which would allow Mariette to become more intimate.

Answer (score 0):

15 seconds before the three approach K, Frey’s JUST told the three that K killed Sapper. Who else would kill Sapper besides a Blade Runner?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This is already stated in RichS's answer, but in a less acerbic way.