# Is Joi an (unwilling) accomplice of either Wallace or the rebellion?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

There are moments in *Blade Runner 2049* where Joi (K's holographic girlfriend) seems to act in ways that help the rebellion:

> Her requesting the prostitute to have sex with K allows the prostitute (who is working with the rebellion) to slip a tracker into K's pocket

But Joi is also a Wallace product and there are moments when one would suspect that Joi is an (unwilling) collaborator:

> Luv is angry when she finds that Joi's holoprojector's antenna is broken off, which suggests that it cannot transmit anymore. But that would imply that it *was* transmitting earlier on.

So which is it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Both - but only unknowingly

### Luv and other mishaps

Joi is a known Wallace Corp. product, Luv even mentions

> I hope the product is to your satisfaction

when Joi's ringtone alerts K in the Wallace Corp. headquarters.

It is evident also, that Luv was using Joi's trackers to keep tabs on K and the progress of his mission. However, there's no evidence that Joi was aware of this happening or aiding it in any way. In fact, before the pair set off to Las Vegas, Joi mentions to K that he needs to remove the antenna and have her fully contained within the 'Emanator' (also removing her backups from the wall unit) in order to not be tracked.

I believe in this case, Joi was telling the truth as Luv displays obvious frustration as soon as the signal is lost and she checks the wall unit.

### Mariette or Marionette?

Now in the case of Mariette and the 'Resistance', Joi still cannot be complicit as she shows no signs thereof. Mariette and the other 'Doxies' were told to approach K in the market by Freysa:

> Go to the man in the green jacket, he's the one who killed [Sapper] Morton. Find out what he knows

Joi just happened to be listening to K and Mariette's conversation and picked up on the vibes between them. That was the reason she called in Mariette specifically for their 'date night'. It was a pure coincidence that worked out well for the Resistance.

### You're such a good Joe

Look, no matter how strange this may seem, I believe that Joi truly *did* 'love' K. In her own way. In fact, that's what she was *programmed to do*. She wasn't a reconnaissance or sabotage agent, she was a purely 'pleasure' device built to give her 'owner' a sense of love, affection and loyalty. Yes, there are potentially tons of the 'Joi' programs out there, but that doesn't make her any less *real*; to K.

Luv was able to track Joi because she seemed like she was an accomplished hacker. She was able to walk into the LAPD, steal a corpse, kill a person and escape; then return later to kill another person. She was able to hack into whatever orbital system it was that she used to 'save' K near the orphanage in the

> now do your fucking job

scene.

The part where K tragically realises that Joi is a simple AI machine designed to tell him everything he wants to hear, including his suggested name "Joe" is another impetus for him to believe that nothing in his life is real. *That's* what makes him do the only real thing left to do: to sacrifice himself for a 'cause'. To finally be human. In fact, he was

> more human than human

Comment: I'd give this +2 if I could.

Comment: I don't think it was a satellite system used to save K near the orphanage, but an in-atmosphere drone.

Comment: +1 It should also be noted for non-native speakers that "Joe" has connotations of "anybody/nobody" in (American) English, such as in the expression "he's just an [average Joe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_Joe)". This underlines not only the fact that *every* Joi is programed to try to make her owner feel special, meaning that in fact *no* owner is special in the end but also K's "averageness" in a disconnected society despite being "special" as a replicant and blade runner; He's just your average Joe, wishing he could be a hero...

Comment: Is there any evidence that Luv hacked into more than Joi's tracker - for example, presumably she'd be able to not only listen into whatever Joi is hearing / has heard, but also what she is seeing.

Comment: @RoboKaren AFAIK there's no direct evidence, but what we see/hear of Joi is just a visualization of a(n albeit very sophisticated) computer program, which also takes in visual and audio input (what Joi "sees" and "hears"). Just as Siri hears everything you say and sends it to the cloud, it would be silly to assume that *not* everything Joi perceives is collected by Wallace Corp: I highly doubt data protection laws are very strict in the BR universe.

Comment: @MikeScott I've changed 'satellite system' to 'orbital system' which conveys the meaning more correctly. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Mooz It's not orbital, either — if it was then it would be a satellite system. It’s flying around in the atmosphere.

Comment: @Möoz it would be extremely unlikely for anything in orbit of man-made size to be visible in daytime in hazy weather; If K saw it as a flash in the sky, it is much more plausible to be some very high-altitude drone/weather balloon-type thing. Also, there is no need for Luv to "hack" it in the typical sense, seeing as she's one of the most important people at the Wallace Corporation, and that company has been shown to have almost limitless power: She likely has unfettered access to anything she wants in the entire universe colonized by man.

Comment: @LincolnMan Thank you. That's very kind.

Comment: "I hope the product is to your satisfaction". By the way, is not K. a Wallace Corp product too?