# Blade Runner 2049: Significance of comment made by hooker to hologram?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

I consider scene where the holographic Joi merges with the replicant hooker and its aftermath incredibly deep. Firstly, that this is Joi's idea is kind of amazing. But the sort of apparently nasty comment: "Quiet now, I've been inside of you and there is not as much there as you think." I believe is very important. Is the hooker merely angry because she was told to be quiet while the hologram was synching and now Joi is telling her she is no longer needed? Okay. But I believe what is important in this scene is the sort of jealousy displayed by both Joi and the replicant -- they both in insulting each other in a way also compliment each other, neither questioning whether the other is "real" or why insult the other? On the other hand, what does the hooker mean about there is not as much there as she thinks? How does having been inside of her give her this information?

Comment: Isn't this heavily opinion based? In any case, I just rewatched the scene and I think the hooker is implying Joi isn't as "genuine" as she presents herself. Joi is fabricated, bundled love, as evidenced in a later scene with a Joi advertisement. The "I've been inside you" line reads to me as a figure of speech; what the hooker means is that she knows what Joi truly is: pre-packaged software, not a "real" person. Just my 2 cents, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

### It's just a subtle dig at Joi to keep her quiet

Technically, they haven't merged in any way, except holographically.

What Mariette is saying to Joi is that she's aware of her core functions: to "say" and "do" whatever her owner needs to hear and see.

This goes against the idea that Joi and K have any form of *real* love or connection as she is purposely programmed to function in the exact manner that *appears* that they do.

See also:

- [Right before Luv destroyed the mobile emanator she says, "I hope you enjoyed our product" -- addressed to whom?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255136/right-before-luv-destroyed-the-mobile-emanator-she-says-i-hope-you-enjoyed-our)
- [Is Joi an (unwilling) accomplice of either Wallace or the rebellion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173087/is-joi-an-unwilling-accomplice-of-either-wallace-or-the-rebellion)
- [Can K feel Joi's touch?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261663/can-k-feel-jois-touch)